# Shorthand code and Fibonnaci Sequence

Tags: python

I have found  example for Fibonacci sequence that goes like this:

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print (b)
        a, b = b, a+b

fib(20)
```

So here's what I don't get it:

```
a, b = 0, 1 # is just a shortcut for writing
a = 0
b = 1
```

right?

Now, following the same logic

```
a, b = b, a+b #should be the same as writing
a = b
b = a+b
```

But it isn't because if I write it like that, the output is different.
I'm having some hard time understanding why. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Yes It isn't exactly the same , because when you write -

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

The value of `a` and `b` at the time of executing the statement is considered, lets say before this statement, `a=1` , `b=2` , then first right hand side is calculated , so `b=2` is calculated and `a+b=3` is calculated. Then the assignment occurs, that is `a` is assigned value `2` and `b` is assigned value `3`.

But when you write -

```
a = b
b = a+b
```

The assignment occurs along with calculation, that is first `b=2` is calculated, then assigned to a , so a becomes 2 , then a+b is calculated (with the changed value of a) , so `a+b=4` and it is assigned to b , so `b` becomes `4` , and hence the difference.

```
a,b = b, a
```

This is a shorthand for swapping values of `a` and `b` , please note that if you want to swap the values without using this notation, you would need a temporary variable.

Internally how it works is that the right hand sid is made into a tuple, and then the values are unpacked, a simple test to see this is -

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 10
>>> t = a, b
>>> t
(5, 10)
>>> b, a = t
```

Answer (score 1):

`a, b = c, d` is *not* shorthand for the following:

```
a = c
b = d
```

It's actually shorthand for this:

```
a, b = (c, d)
```

I.e., you're creating a tuple `(c, d)`, a tuple with the values of `c` and `d`, which is then [*unpacked*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) into the target list `a, b`. The tuple with its values is created before the values are unpacked into the target list. It actually *is* one atomic* operation, not a shorthand for several operations. So it does not matter whether one of the variables in the target list also occurs on the right hand side of the assignment operation.

<sub>* Not "atomic" in the sense of database ACID, but still not separate statements.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It is not the same thing.

`x, y = y, x`

equals to:

> t = x
> x = y
> y = t

It actually uses a temporary variable to swap `x` and `y`.

So back to `a, b = b, a+b`. This expression equals to:

> m = a; n = b
>
> a = n
>
> b = m + n